# Enum и как его выводить в массив?

Tags: java

Ну есть `Enum` в которой 3 переменные Moдerator Inkvizitor и God. Как мне вывести их значения в массив? И обладает ли `enum` какими-то привилегиями в отличии от `class`-а или недостатками, потому что оба имеют поля и можно писать в них методы.

Comment: конечно, самое главное - enum объект нельзя создать через new. Поэтому их всегда можно через == сравнивать. Ну а работать как и с любым другим объектом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `YourEnum.values()` для получения массива всех возможных вариантов перечисления.

Перечисление удобнее класса тогда, когда вы планируете не расширяемое количество экземпляров объекта. Например перечисление хранящее пол человека `Sex.Male` и `Sex.Female`. Также перечисления могут иметь методы, например:

```
enum Sex { 
   MALE, FEMALE;

   public String prefix() {
      return this == MALE ? "mr." : "mrs.";
   } 
}
```

или

```
enum Sex { 
   MALE { 
        public String prefix() { return "mr."; } 
   }, 
   FEMALE { 
        public String prefix() { return "mrs."; } 
   }; 

   public abstract String prefix(); 
}
```